# How to boot using EFI with custom Ubuntu 22 image?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, uefi, bios

I have a customized Ubuntu ISO, generated with genisoimage until Ubuntu 20. Unfortunately, Ubuntu 22.04 removed isolinux from its ISO, see here: https://github.com/covertsh/ubuntu-preseed-iso-generator/issues/5

I'm moving to xorriso to build an Ubuntu 22 ISO with this commands:

```
dd if=ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso bs=1 count=432 of=/tmp/boot_hybrid.img
dd if=ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso bs=512 skip=7129428 count=8496 of=/tmp/efi.img

xorriso -as mkisofs -r \
  -V 'Ubuntu 22.04 LTS MODIF (EFIBIOS)' \
  -o output/custom_ubuntu22.iso \
  --grub2-mbr /tmp/boot_hybrid.img \
  -partition_offset 16 \
  --mbr-force-bootable \
  -append_partition 2 28732ac11ff8d211ba4b00a0c93ec93b /tmp/efi.img \
  -appended_part_as_gpt \
  -iso_mbr_part_type a2a0d0ebe5b9334487c068b6b72699c7 \
  -c 'boot.catalog' \
  -b 'boot/grub/i386-pc/eltorito.img' \
 -no-emul-boot \
  -boot-load-size 4 \
  -boot-info-table \
  --grub2-boot-info \
  -eltorito-alt-boot \
  -e '--interval:appended_partition_2:::' \
  -no-emul-boot \
  ./iso
```

Here is what happens when I try to use EFI in VirtualBox:
[image]
[image]

Booting without EFI works fine.

I'm using ddrescue to create a bootable USB key, it's not working anymore with this new ISO.

How can I make this ISO bootable on EFI?

Thanks!

Comment: Do not know genisoimage, but the UEFI boot file is /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi for all external devices and often the fallback boot entry in UEFI for internal devices. The change Ubuntu made was to use grub for both UEFI & BIOS boot. Where before grub was just UEFI boot and syslinux was for BIOS boot.  The Ubuntu has a standard /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi, but not sure if that is what you want or not.

Comment: The file /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi exists in the ISO, is this what you meant?

Comment: Should be. Each version of bootx64.efi may be different. Windows also uses bootx64.efi for its installer. And live installer is different than that of a full install.

Comment: Interesting! I can boot using a not modified ISO, but I can't with the customized one. I create the USB key with the same method for both.